# How to use VBR on transcoder API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-transcoder

I'm trying to use VBR on elementaryStreams, but there's no documentation about it. It accepts an string and just it.

```
elementaryStreams: [
  {
    key: 'video-stream',
    videoStream: {
      h265: {
        heightPixels: 1080,
        widthPixels: 1920,
        bitrateBps: 12288000,
        rateControlMode: 'VBR', // Here.
        frameRate: 60,
      },
    },
  },
],
```

Is setting VBR suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a documentation for using this method in a [constructor](https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/cloud-video-transcoder/latest/V1beta1.VideoStream) (another here for [job config](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/reference/rest/v1/JobConfig)) and it appears that it is set in vbr by default.

> rateControlMode   string
>
> Specify the rateControlMode. The default is "vbr". Supported rate control modes: - 'vbr' - variable bitrate - 'crf' - constant rate factor
>
> The default is vbr.

Please see some configuration samples [here](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/concepts/config-examples#video_stream) for your reference.